# Evaluating complex functions integrals over closed curves

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I recently evaluated the following two integrals:

1. $\int_\gamma \dfrac{\bar z\,dz}{2i}$ where $\gamma$ is a circle with radius $r$ around some point.
2. $\int_\gamma \dfrac{\bar z\,dz}{2i}$ where $\gamma$ is a rectangle in the complex plane.

In the two cases the value of the integral was the area of the curve i.e $\pi r^2 $ and the rectangle's area.

Why is it so? Is it something special with this integrand?

Can I make a shortcut using these 2 to evaluate $\int_\gamma e^z \, dz$ over the rectangle which its points lie on $0,1,1+i,i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That contour integral works out to be $$(1/2)\int_\gamma (x\,dy -y\,dx) -(i/2)\int_\gamma (x\,dx +y\,dy).$$

The first integral equals the area inside $\gamma$ (if $\gamma$ is a nice simple closed curve) by Green's theorem. The second integral is the work done by a conservative field over a closed curve, hence equals $0.$